# Is there any way to view/download the script/files that are hidden in SuiteBundle in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I just want to know that is there any way to view or download the script/files that are checked as hidden in suitebundle in netsuite?
I have seen some suite bundles that have some files that are hidden. While downloading the bundle folder, I have seen that all files that are marked as **'HIDE IN SUITEBUNDLE'** are not available.

[image: NetSuite SuiteBundle File Page]

Answer (score 0):

No. Files marked that way are done so to prevent them from being downloaded/viewed in accounts where the bundle is installed. Typically this is done to protect the developer's IP.